# Check if the following sets are open/closed

Tags: general-topology

**Question:**
Check if the following sets are open and/or closed and compute $\operatorname{int}(A) $ and $\bar A$.

a. $A=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: 0 \le x+y<2\}$

b. $A=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:x^2+2y^2<1\}$

#### What have we tried

Bounding, triangle inequality, Pythagoras theorem. We're having a very hard time proving these formally. Intuitively it's pretty obvious that a is not closed for example. We're supposed to use the method of balls and reductio ad absurdum.

Comment: a) is actually closed

Comment: Yes, because Mustafa said.

Comment: I made a typo in A. fixed now

Comment: $(x,y) ↦ x + y$ and $(x,y) ↦ x^2 + 2y^2$ are sooo continuous, $[0..2] ⊂ ℝ$ is sooo closed, $(-∞..1) ⊂ ℝ$ is soooo open, and openness/closedness is sooooo preserved under preimages of continuous functions.

Comment: haven't studied continuous functions in relation to these. This is a actually the first question I'm trying to solve in this subject as I have first heard of it a week ago. And I've spent the last 5 hours trying to handle this question..

Comment: @AustinMohr I don’t understand: Since $f \colon ℝ^2 → ℝ,\, (x,y) ↦ x^2 +2y^2$ is continuous and $A = f^{-1} ((-∞..1))$, we know $A ⊂ ℝ^2$ is open, don’t we?

Comment: @K.Stm. You're right. I misread the definition of the set. I knew something was awry even as I typed my objection...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint A:**

Let $A$ be the set in part (a). Pick $(x,y)$ such that $x + y = 0$. Is it possible to find a small open ball around $(x,y)$ such that the ball remains entirely in $A$? What do you conclude?

Next, pick $(x,y)$ such that $x + y = 2$. Is it possible to find a small open ball around $(x,y)$ such that the ball remains entirely in $A^c$? What do you conclude?

**Hint B:**

Let $B$ be the set in part (b). Pick any $(x,y) \in B$ and let $d$ be the shortest distance from $(x,y)$ to the ellipse $x^2 + 2y^2 = 1$ (such a distance exists - we need not specify it exactly). What can you say about the ball centered at $(x,y)$ with radius $d/2$?

Answer (score 1):

In B, your set is the inverse image of an open interval under the map $(x,y)\mapsto x^2 + 2y^2$. It is therefore open.

In A, any point along the line $y=-x$ is a boundary point of your set. Since these boundary points lie in the set, your set cannot be open.